# Remove horizontal line after caption in longtable

Tags: captions, longtable

I have a particularly long table which spread across pages. I want a horizontal line to come at the end of the table at each page. The problem is when I use "\hline \endfoot" a horizontal line also appears after the caption. Is there a way to fix that? I don't want the horizontal line to appear after the caption.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}


\geometry{a4paper,tmargin=3.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=1.5cm, headheight=3em, headsep=1.5cm, footskip=1cm}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{mColor1}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, subcaption, setspace, booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{url, lipsum}

\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\onehalfspacing
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\begin{document}


\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{| p{2.5cm} | p{2.2cm} | p{2cm} |p{2cm} |p{2.5cm} |p{3.8cm} |p{4cm} |p{3cm}|}  \hline\rowcolor{mColor1} Form Filename&Date&Status&Charge ID&Amount&Charge is on&ROI&Certificate Filename  \endhead  \hline
\endfoot Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\\hline           \caption{hello}\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can just add in `\endlastfoot` after your `\endfoot`. Basically `\endlastfoot`command will only be used for the very last footer, while `\endfoot` will be used for all others. Read the `longtable` package documentation for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that you wrote command `\caption{...}` at the end of the table.

A `longtable` has a special structure you should use. Please read the documentation (use `texdoc longtable` on your terminal/console)!

Just add after command `\endfoot` the following code:

```
  \hline      % <=======================================================
  \caption{hello} % <===================================================
\endlastfoot  % <=======================================================
```

to get what you want.

After some pretty printing and deleted not used packages here you get the following MWE

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{%
  a4paper,tmargin=3.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=1.5cm, 
  headheight=3em, headsep=1.5cm, footskip=1cm
}

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mColor1}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\onehalfspacing
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{| p{2.5cm} | p{2.2cm} | p{2cm} |p{2cm} |p{2.5cm} |p{3.8cm} |p{4cm} |p{3cm}|}  
  \hline
  \rowcolor{mColor1} Form Filename&Date&Status&Charge ID&Amount&Charge is on&ROI&Certificate Filename \\
  \hline
\endhead  
  \hline
\endfoot 
  \hline      % <=======================================================
  \caption{hello} % <===================================================
\endlastfoot  % <=======================================================
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
%\hline           % <===================================================
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

with the resulting last table page:

[image: last table page]

## EDIT:

To get a better result I suggest some changings in your table.

1. A long table better has a heading at the beginning of the table (see code from beginning of the table until `\endfirsthead`.  In the code for the `\endfoot` you can add a notice that table is to be continued ... See for more informations the documentation of `longtable` (for example with `texdoc longtable`).
2. I deleted the color for your first table row and I deleted the vertical lines. The result is a better looking table imho.
3. With using packages `ragged2e` and `array` you get a command `\RaggedRight` which allows a better hyphenating in your table columns. For example use `>{\RaggedRight}p{2.5cm}` to get the first column left justified with better hyphenation.
4. With `\usepackage{booktabs}` you can use the commands `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` to get nice horizontal rules in your table where needed.

Please see the following MWE (code changes marked with `<=========`):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{%
  a4paper,tmargin=3.5cm, bmargin=2.5cm, lmargin=1.5cm, rmargin=1.5cm, 
  headheight=3em, headsep=1.5cm, footskip=1cm
}

\usepackage{longtable,array} % <========================================
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs} % <========== \toprule etc.
\usepackage{ragged2e} % <========== \RaggedRight

\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\onehalfspacing
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{>{\RaggedRight}p{2.5cm} >{\RaggedRight}p{1.5cm}  >{\RaggedRight}p{2cm} >{\RaggedRight}p{2cm} >{\RaggedRight}p{2.5cm} >{\RaggedRight}p{3.8cm} >{\RaggedRight}p{4cm} >{\RaggedRight}p{3cm}}  
%\begin{longtable}{p{2.5cm}  p{1.5cm}  p{2cm} p{2cm} p{2.5cm} p{3.8cm} p{4cm} p{3cm}}
  \caption{hello} \\ % <================================================
  \toprule
  Form Filename&Date&Status&Charge ID&Amount&Charge is on&ROI&Certificate Filename \\
  \midrule
\endfirsthead  
  \toprule
  Form Filename&Date&Status&Charge ID&Amount&Charge is on&ROI&Certificate Filename \\
  \midrule
\endhead  
  \midrule
  to be continued \\
  \bottomrule
\endfoot 
  \bottomrule      % <===================================================
% \caption{hello} % <===================================================
\endlastfoot  % <=======================================================
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
Form 8-190706.do&-&Modification&80006325&500,000,000&Furniture, Plant Machinery, Book debts, Stock in trade&-&-\\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image: resulting table]

Comment: (i) i would discourage op to have caption on the end of table, specially at long table is far better to have it on the top of table, (ii) similarly to have colored the first row, (iii)  columns i would define with `>{RaggedRight}{p{...}` and add `ragged2e` package in preamble ... however, it seem that op already forgot on her/his question ... :-)

Comment: nice answer, thank you! sorry, but i cant vote twice :-(